# Is sum of $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{p}{(n(n+1)}\mod{p})= \frac{p(p-1)}{2} $ where $p \equiv 7 \mod{8}$ correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{p-1}{(n^{2}+n)}\mod{p})= \frac{p(p-1)}{2} $ where $p \equiv 7 \mod{8}$

I am not sure if this is correct, this is a part of my homework and is having trouble with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint :

$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{p-1}{(n^{2}+n)}\mod{p}= \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{p-1}{(n^{2}}\mod{p}) + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{p-1}{(n}\mod{p})$

Sum the $ p-1$ squares followed by summing up $p-1$ terms in the next expression. 
I do not think that the RHS is fully worked out.

Comment: well, aren't sum of all quadratic residue just $0$? and we summed it up twice and $ \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{p-1}{(n}\mod{p}) = \frac{p(p-1)}{2}$

Comment: Yes,you can also work out the sum of quadratic residues directly. As for the second expression, you have $ \frac{p-1}{2}$ is an integer and so $p$ divides the expression. Therefore, the sum is $0$.